# If for some field getText() returns NULL then what other functions could use to get the string of that field?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I was asked this question in an interview.

If you cannot get the string by `getText()` because it returns `NULL`. Then how would you get the string of a field in selenium webdriver?

Answer (score 0):

There can be several ways:

Using selenium with getting the attributes of the element:
InnerText can be empty in some cases, thats why you can also try with innerHTML.

```
var innertext = element.getAttribute("innerText");
var innerHtml = element.getAttribute("innerHTML");
```

Or you can execute js script

```
var element = element(by.id('something');

var response = browser.executeScript('var el = arguments[0]; return {text: el.innerText, html: el.innerHTML};', element);

console.log(response.text)
console.log(response.html)
```

There is also a variant of execute script from selenium, *document query* element and return the innerText or innerHTML or and other property from it.